# Appending individual lists created from a list comprehension using values from input()

Tags: list, list-comprehension

I created a list comprehension to provide me the following:

listoflists = [[] for i in range(252*5)]

I then simplified the list in variable newlists to contain only the number of lists in range(weeks) which is a dynamic variable.

I want to append each individual list in the following loop for a specified range with the append process moving through each list after its reached a specified length. The values are generated from an input function. For instance, if the first list in newlists exceeds a length of 5 I want the values following the 5th loop to then append to the next list and so on. The code I currently have is:

```
  p = 0
  singlist = []
  listoflists = [[] for i in range(252*5)]
  newlists= [listoflists[i] for i in range(weeks)]
  while p<(int(people)*weeks): #fix appending process
       for i in range(int(people)*weeks):
       weekly =input("Put your hours: ")
       singlist.append(int(weekly))
       p += 1
       if weekly.isalpha() == True:
        print("Not a valid amount of time")

 for i in range(0,weeks):
     while len(newlists[i])<int(people):
     newlists[i].append(singlist[i])
```

This code however appends the same values to all lists in range weeks. What is the most efficient way to fix this? Thank you!

if singlist = [10,15,20,25]
desire output for newlists is: [[10,15],[20,25]]

How I've structured the program:

```
    import sys
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from datetime import tzinfo,timedelta,datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import itertools as it
from itertools import count,islice

team = []
y = 0 
while y == 0:
    try:
        people = input("How many people are on your engagement? ")
        if people.isdigit() == True:
            y += 1
    except:
        print("Not a number try again")

z= 0
while z<int(people):
        for i in range(int(people)):
                names = input("Name: ")
                if names.isalpha() == False:
                    team.append(names)
                    z+=1
                elif names.isdigit() == True:
                    print("Not a name try again")



ties = [] # fix looping for more than one person
e = 0
while e<int(people):
    for i in range(int(people)):
        title = input("What is their title: ")
        if title.isdigit() == True:
            print("Not a title try again")
        else:
            ties.append(title)
            e+=1


values = [] #fix looping for more than one person
t= 0
while t <int(people):
    for i in range(int(people)):
        charge = input("How much are you charging for them: ")
        if charge.isalpha() == True:
            print("Not a valid rate")
        else:
            values.append(int(charge))
            t +=1


weeks = int(input("How many weeks are you including: "))
days = []
x = 0
while x<weeks: #include a parameter for dates of a 7 day difference to only be permitted
    try:
        for i in range(int(weeks)):
            dates = input("Input the dates (mm/dd/yy): ")
            dt_start = datetime.strptime(dates,'%m/%d/%y')
            days.append(dates)
            x+=1
    except:
        print("Incorrect format")            


p = 0
singlist = []
listoflists = [[] for i in range(252*5)]
newlists= [listoflists[i] for i in range(weeks)]
while p<(int(people)*weeks): #fix appending process
    for i in range(int(people)*weeks):
        weekly =input("Put your hours: ")
        singlist.append(int(weekly))
        p += 1
        if weekly.isalpha() == True:
            print("Not a valid amount of time")


def func(items,n):
    items = iter(items)
    for i in it.count():
        out = it.islice(items,weeks*i,weeks*i+n)
        if not out:
            break
output = list(func(singlist,weeks))
```

Comment: The number of `len()` functions might indicate, that there is a better way to do it. Can you tell the original problem for which you wrote this code.

Comment: I edited the code above with the new code that I've written and added the desired output hopefully that will help understand; the problem I'm solving is creating a dynamic budgeting tool where there are multiple input loops whose values aggregate to a dataframe. The desired output I want is in the above edits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# items = [1,2,3,...n]
# output = [[1,2],[3,4],..], n = 2 elements each
items_ = iter(items)
outiter = iter(lambda: [next(items_) for i in range(n)],[])
outlist = list(outiter)
```

You can do the same thing using `while` loop in place of `count()` and `[a:b]` slice operation on list instead of `islice()`. But using iterators is very efficient.

Comment: thank you! what function is the iter(items) function? I just ran the code and I am receiving 'module' object is not callable

Comment: `iter()` is a builtin function. Are you getting the error on that line? type `iter` at the interpreter, tell me what it says.

Comment: I fixed that issue now had to restart my kernel, but I ran the code in the restarted environment an it is now frozen at that line of code. May be the amount of memory I have on my comp

Comment: ok, do one thing, tell me where are you getting the `items` list from?

Comment: the items list is coming from the singlist variable in my first post in the body of the for loop within the while loop

Comment: I've added the program to my original post for further clarification

Comment: I edited the program. Try these three lines. They work on my computer.

Comment: It works, you are awesome! Your assistance is very much appreciate!

Comment: Thanks. Always try to get things done with iterators and generators. So that you can focus more on logic, not on list indices.